# Given a linear operator $T$, show that $W = null(T - 2I)$ has no complementary $T$-invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I am self-studying out of Hoffman and Kunze's *Linear Algebra*. In the section on cyclic decomposition and the rational form, exercise 3 asks:

> Let $T$ be the linear operator on $R^3$ which is represented in the standard ordered basis by the matrix
>
> $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}2&0&0\\1&2&0\\0&0&3\end{array}\right]$$
>
> Let $W$ be the null space of $T - 2I$. Prove that $W$ has no complementary $T$-invariant subspace.

A hint is given:

> *Hint*: Let $\beta = \epsilon_1$ and observe that $(T - 2I)\beta$ is in $W$. Prove there is no $\alpha$ in $W$ with $(T - 2I)\beta = (T - 2I)\alpha$.

Following the suggestions, $(T - 2I)\beta = (0,1,0)$. Now, $W$ must be one-dimensional by rank-nullity, and $null(T-2I) = span\{(0,1,0)\}$; since $\beta \in W$, there is no $\alpha \in W$ such that $(T - 2I)\alpha = (T - 2I)\beta$, since $\alpha \in W \implies (T-2I)\alpha = 0 \neq (0,1,0) = (T - 2I)\beta$.

However, I do not see how to proceed from this observation to the conclusion that $W$ has no complementary, $T$-invariant subspace. In particular, I do not see how to use the cyclic decomposition theorem; indeed, it seems that if I could apply it, it would, in fact, yield a complementary $T$-admissible subspace.

I observe that $\beta$ is in the null space of $(T-2I)^2$, but do not see how to make use of this either, unless I am to find the primary decomposition, but this does not seem to help and seems out of place for an exercise in the section on cyclic decomposition.

What is the correct direction here?

Comment: can you please remind me what a complementary subspace is?

Comment: It's a subspace whose intersection with the given subspace is $\{0\}$. But it is $(T-2I)$ which sends $\beta$ into $W$, not $T$, since $\beta \in null(T-2I)^2 \supset null(T-2I) = W$.

Comment: why is not $span\{(1,0,0)^T, (0,0,1)^T\}$ a complementary subspace of $W = span\{(0,1,0)^T\}?$

Comment: It is, but it is not a $T$-invariant one. $T(1,0,0) = (2,1,0) \not \in span\{(1,0,0),(0,0,1)\}$... oh. Then why this business with $T-2I$ and $\beta$?

Comment: what has invariance got to do with the subspace being complementary? are you adding more constraint that $T$ restricted to the complementary subspace should not have $2$ for an eigenvalue?

Comment: I do not see what the definitions of a $T$-invariant subspace and a complementary subspace have to do with each other. It is true that the null space of $(T-cI)^k$, where $c$ is an eigenvalue for $T$, is invariant under $T$. 

In this case, $T$ has eigenvalues $2$ and $3$, and the associated subspaces are $span\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ and $span\{(0,0,1)\}$, respectively. However, that does not mean that there cannot be other invariant subspaces - does it?

Comment: we can prove that the complementary subspace $\{(1,0,0)^T, (0,0,1)^T\}$ of $W = span\{(0,1,0)^T\}$ is not $T$-invariant. is that way you want?

Comment: That seems to be enough of an argument to me.

Comment: The title has the "$T$-invariant" condition, but the highlighted part of the question body does not. This is confusing; please add the condition in the body too.

Comment: Corrected; apologies for the omission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U$ is a $T$-stable complementary subspace to $W=\ker(T-2I)$ then one can write $\epsilon_1=u+w$ with $u\in U$ and $w\in W$. Then $\epsilon_2=(T-2I)(\epsilon_1)=(T-2I)(u+w)=(T-2I)(u)$, which is in$~U$ by $T$-stability of the latter, but also $\epsilon_2\in W$. This is in contradiction with $U\cap W=\{0\}$.

This tries to use (part of) the given hint. However one can also reason as follows. If $U$ were a $T$-stable complementary subspace of $\ker(T-2I)$, then the restriction of $T-2I$ to $U$ is well defined and injective (since its kernel is $\ker(T-2I)\cap U=\{0\}$). But then writing an arbitrary vector $v=u+w$ one sees that $(T-2I)^2(v)=0$ implies $u=0$ and therefore already $(T-2I)(v)=0$, which contradicts the fact that there are vectors in the kernel of $(T-2I)^2$ that are not in the kernel of $T-2I$ (for instance $\epsilon_1$ is such a vector).

Comment: That makes complete sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

<s>At abel's guidance in comments on the original question, the answer is simple. Observe that $W = span\{(0,1,0)\}$. Then, a complementary subspace of $W$ would have to be spanned by $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. However, $T(1,0,0) = (2,1,0)$, which is not spanned by those vectors, and so the complementary subspace of $W$ is not $T$-invariant.</s>

I'm not sure what the hint was there for.

This is incorrect as per the below comment. See [Marc's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1089980/169845).

Comment: This is not correct. There are (infinitely) many complementary subspaces of $W$, you cannot assume the complementary subsapce has to be the one spanned by $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.